# How to validate two fields in one error in Jquery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a two fields of date_start and date_end and I want to validate both in jQuery Validate.

I have a two error from validator but I need just one...

[image]

part of java JSP form

```
<div class="form-group user-edit-form-group">
  <label for="input_cameras_limit" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Cameras limit</label>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input name="key_cameras_limit" id="input_cameras_limit" type="text"
    class="form-control user-edit-input" placeholder="" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="user-edit-error-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS validation part

```
$('#partner_key_settings_form').validate({

    rules: {
        key_valid_from: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        key_valid_till: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        }

    },
    messages: {
        key_valid_from: {
            required: JsMultiLang.getWords('partner', 'validationPromoCodeDate')

        },
        key_valid_till: {
            required: JsMultiLang.getWords('partner', 'validationPromoCodeDate')
        }
    },

    errorClass: "user-search-error",

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        if (element.attr("name")=="key_valid_from" ||element.attr("name")=="key_valid_till"){
             error.appendTo($(element).parent().parent().parent().find('.user-edit-error-wrapper'));
             console.log(error.appendTo($(element).parent().parent().parent().find('.user-edit-error-wrapper')==undefined))
        }

    },

    highlight: function (element) {
        $(".user-edit-server-error").remove();
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');

        var tabPaneId = $(element).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + tabPaneId + '"]').addClass('has-error');
    },

    unhighlight: function (element, error, valid) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

        var tabPaneId = $(element).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
        var hasErrorDivsId = '#' + tabPaneId + ' .has-error';
        var errorDivsOnTabSize = $(hasErrorDivsId).size();
        if (errorDivsOnTabSize < 1) {
            $('a[href="#' + tabPaneId + '"]').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    },

    success: function (error) {
        error.remove();

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `group` `object` for grouping the validation and `errorPlacement` if you needed.

```
rules: {
    key_valid_from: {
      required: true,
      date: true
    },
    key_valid_till: {
      required: true,
      date: true
    }

  },
  groups: {
    key_valid_from: "key_valid_from key_valid_till"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "key_valid_from" || element.attr("name") == "key_valid_till")
      error.insertAfter('input[name=key_valid_till]');
    else
      error.insertAfter(element);
  }
```